# Java compilation UNIX - classpath usage

Tags: java, compilation, classpath

Let us assume the following folder structure for a project:
*ProjectName/src/package_name*

All the source files necessary for compilation are in the *package_name* folder.

While trying to compile the program from the *package_name* folder with `java ClassName` command, an error occurs (**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**).

The analogical command used in the *src* folder (`java package_name/ClassName`) is, on the other hand correct.

In my understanding, this is because

> If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, the
>                 user class path consists of the current directory (.).

However, while in *ProjectName/src/package_name*, `java -cp .. ClassName` yields the aforementioned error, although I reckon it should be equivalent to `java -cp . package_name/ClassName` in one directory above.

Similarly, while trying to run the program from different locations on the disc (using both local and absolute paths), I am getting the same error.

Any idea why?

EDIT:

What is startling, command `java -cp .. package_name/ClassName` (as well as its counterpart with '.' which produces the same result) now throws a different error. In *ProjectName/files* I have some .txt files which my program is reading, and the aforementioned command throws FileNotFoundException, while `java package_name/ClassName` from src directory doesn't. It would imply that the directory from which you run the file affects the point at which relative path is being calculated. Is it so?

Comment: No. `java package_name.ClassName` - not sure why you thought a slash was allowed there. And `package_name` is part of the classes name.